# Why does spark-submit take longer than running the same job using spark-shell?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am running the same job first using spark-shell and then spark-submit. But, spark-submit takes much longer. I am running this on a 16 node cluster (>180 Vcores) in client mode.

spark-submit conf:

```
spark-submit --class tool \
    --master yarn \
    --deploy-mode client \
    --conf "spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer" \
    --conf "spark.kryo.classesToRegister=com.fastdtw.timeseries.TimeSeriesBase" \
    --executor-memory 14g \
    --driver-memory 16g \
    --conf "spark.driver.maxResultSize=16g" \
    --conf "spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=512" \
    --num-executors 30 \
    --conf "spark.executor.cores=6" \
    /home/target/scala-2.10/tool_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

spark-shell conf:

```
spark-shell \
  --master yarn 
  --deploy-mode client \
  --conf "spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer" \
  --conf "spark.kryo.classesToRegister=com.fastdtw.timeseries.TimeSeriesBase" \
  --executor-memory 12g \
  --driver-memory 16g \
  --conf "spark.driver.maxResultSize=16g" \
  --conf "spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max=512" \
  --conf "spark.executor.cores=6" \
  --conf "spark.executor.instances=30"
```

Why is there a difference at runtime?

Comment: When you say "takes longer", how do you measure the time? Are you using web UI to see the completion times or some other means, e.g. SparkListeners?

Comment: Using the webUI to see completion and the stages.

Comment: The numbers for executors and memory are different. Could you please attach the respective pages from web UI you use to compare both executions?

Comment: When you are running things on cluster, different executors reside on different nodes which means that the inter-executor communication involves the use of network. Which means that every repartition potentially sends all your data over network, which takes time... a lot of time. And that is the reason behind people trying to avoid re-shuffles.

Comment: But in both cases thats happening. So why does the difference exist? and I compared the Web UI for the number of executors and cores used. Its the same.

Comment: The memory, 14g or 12g doesn't make much difference. I tried both.